# Maven archetype What is keepParent option for

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a set of archetype project which all inherit from same parent pom.
All archetypes generate concret projects whose pom inherit from the company parent pom.

I didn't manage to get what is the `keepParent` option behavior of `archetype:create-from-project` goal.

Can someone explains me what's the option behavior in a more detailed way than in the maven docs ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keepParent option is true by default and does not seem to have any effect when set to false: a quick look at the code (I checked out v2.2) shows that it is not implemented. Still, it would quite useful to avoid generating the parent snippet in the generated archetype.

Fyi, the doc can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#keepParent
and the code can be accessed from: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/source-repository.html